Ubuntu Server - Auto mount drive using the terminal
First off thanks for looking at my question!
I just set up Ubuntu Server (Latest version with all updates applied)
The machine has 2 drives in the system.

1x - 256GB NVME drive (OS installed)
1x - 12TB SATA drive. (Blank Data Drive)

When I run the mount command, I have no issues. The drive mounts and it seems based on what I have read, everything is working as it should.
fdisk Command
sudo fdisk -l

fdisk output
Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 238.47 GiB, 256060514304 bytes, 500118192 sectors
Disk model: WDC PC SN720 SDAPNTW-256G-1006
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 51BFBD93-94E5-4263-BBB2-1285969BB71E

Device           Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1    2048   2203647   2201600     1G EFI System
/dev/nvme0n1p2 2203648 500115455 497911808 237.4G Linux filesystem


Disk /dev/sda: 10.91 TiB, 12000138625024 bytes, 23437770752 sectors
Disk model: ST12000VN0008-2Y
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 57ECE6AC-4C95-4A32-B705-314B74FED57C

Device     Start         End     Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sda1   2048 23437770718 23437768671 10.9T Linux filesystem


Disk /dev/sdb: 7.27 GiB, 7803174912 bytes, 15240576 sectors

After running the mount command it seems like the drive is mounted to /drives/12TB:
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /drives/12TB

Verification:
Command:
df

Output:
Filesystem       1K-blocks    Used   Available Use% Mounted on
tmpfs               790236    4652      785584   1% /run
efivarfs               150      85          61  59% /sys/firmware/efi/efivars
/dev/nvme0n1p2   243937628 6965644   224507808   4% /
tmpfs              3951176       0     3951176   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                 5120       0        5120   0% /run/lock
/dev/nvme0n1p1     1098632    6284     1092348   1% /boot/efi
tmpfs               790232      12      790220   1% /run/user/1000
/dev/sda1      11625468300    2076 11039505624   1% /drives/12TB

Now if I were to reboot, we all know the mount point would be lost. It is at this point, I am completely unsure what I am doing wrong...
fstab
I have read online the next step is to edit "fstab" to have it load the mount automatically each time the machine boots up.
I then type
Command:
sudo blkid /dev/sda1

Output
/dev/sda1: UUID="761734ab-1615-4dd0-8a05-286cb4662333" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="fd2c8ff4-759b-40b9-aef3-43d7d71002bb"

I then backup the fstab config:
Command:
sudo cp /etc/fstab /etc/fstab.bkp

Then I edit fstab with nano
sudo nano /etc/fstab

I believe up until now I have done everything correctly.
Using the last command I have tried both UUID and PARTUUID.
At the end of the file, I added these lines one at a time. Each time I make a change I remove the previous line and update it with different parameters. I put all 4 items that I tried in one section here on StackExchange just to make it easier for someone to read.
first two lines I used the UUIDs and in the second one I tried using PARTUUID.
UUID="c9ded0c1-19ff-4944-93a5-8b72375296fb" /drives/12TB ext4 defaults 0 0
UUID="c9ded0c1-19ff-4944-93a5-8b72375296fb" /drives/12TB ext4 defaults 0 2
/dev/disk/by-uuid/fd2c8ff4-759b-40b9-aef3-43d7d71002bb /drivers/12TB ext4 defaults 0 0
/dev/disk/by-uuid/fd2c8ff4-759b-40b9-aef3-43d7d71002bb /drivers/12TB ext4 defaults 0 2

It is after I save this file that things start to go sideways...
On reboot, it fails to mount the drive:
Job dev-disk-by\x2duuid-c9ded0c1\x2d4944\x2d8b72375296fb.device/start running(1 min / 1 min 30s)

Thank you if you made it this far :) I appreciate any help I can get.

What say latest Ubuntu Server, please just say Ubuntu 24.10 Server if that's what you're using.  If you modify the file-system table you don't need to reboot to test; you can (if it /drives/12TB was unmounted), just mount -a or mount /drives/12TB to test it.

hi @jared-heinrichs Not an answer but I just noticed difference between first and last 2 lines. Is there a typo in /etc/fstab entries? First 2 lines says, /drives/12TB, while last 2 lines says, /drivers/12TB. Thanks.

As you've mentioned, output of sudo blkid /dev/sda1 is: /dev/sda1: UUID="761734ab-1615-4dd0-8a05-286cb4662333" ..., yet later in /etc/fstab, you've typed: UUID="c9ded0c1-19ff-4944-93a5-8b72375296fb" . Why these two are different? Thanks.

@jags - Thanks a bunch. I had an incorrect UUID. What ended up resolving the issue was this line: UUID="761734ab-1615-4dd0-8a05-286cb4662333" /drives/12TB ext4 defaults 0 0 I appreciate the extra set of eyes on this one.
